как добавить значение переменной к переменной из пропсов?
у меня есть 2 переменные, которые я расположил в основном компоненте - Num1 и Num2
При нажатии на кнопку с цифрой мы переменной NumberValue(которая находится в дочернем компоненте, как и сама функция) задаем значение '9' и в зависимости от условия прибавляем к пропсовым переменным.
На страницу значение Num1 и Num2 выводятся в инпут поля, которые расположены в отдельных компонентах.
Все переменные отображаются корректно. Не работает именно прибавление NumberValue к Num1/Num2
NumberClick() {
          this.ButtonNumber = !this.ButtonNumber
          this.NumberValue = '9'

          if(this.sum || this.umno || this.delit || this.mins == false) {
            this.Num1 += this.NumberValue
          } else {
            this.Num2 += this.NumberValue
          }

          setTimeout(() => {
            this.ButtonNumber = !this.ButtonNumber
          }, 500)
        },


В Vue считается некорректным менять входные параметры. Лучше будет сгенерировать событие, а уже основной компонент пусть меняет Num1 или Num2.
